# come from back navigation app not refreshing in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, flutter-navigation

When i am on edit profile screen i changed my details and back from the back icon, On the next screen my updated data not reflecting.

This is my home screen where i need to call below API:

Main.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      showPerformanceOverlay: false,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'hempmeASAP',
      home: (is_loggedin) ? Home():Login(),
      routes: {
        "/home": (_) => new Home(),
        "/login": (_) => new Login(),
        "/signup": (_) => new Signup(),
        "/forgot": (_) => new ForgotPassword()
      },
    );
  }
```

home.dart

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getProfileData();
}

getProfileData() {
    customFun.readToken().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        access_token = val;
      });
      try{
        (() async {
         await restApis.getProfile(access_token).then((val) => setState((){
            print(val);
            name = (val["data"]["name"]).toString();
            profile_img = val["data"]["avatarUrl"];

          }));
        })();
      }catch(e){
        setState(() {
          showProgressBar = false;
          //show_error = true;
          //error_msg = "The exception thrown is $e";
        });
        scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          content: Text("The exception thrown is $e"),
        ));
      }
    });
  }
```

// I need to pass updated name and profile_img here

```
child: new Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        //drawer: new Drawer(child: DrawerList()),
        appBar: AppBarComponent(context: context, appbarTitle:appBarTitle, name: name, profile_img: profile_img),
)
```

app_bar_component.dart

```
class AppBarComponent extends AppBar {

  AppBarComponent({Key key, BuildContext context, appbarTitle, name, profile_img, screenName})
    : super(
    key: key,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    //centerTitle: false,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Color(0xff888888), //change your color here
    ),
    title: Container(
      child: Row(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
         children: <Widget>[
           Stack(
             children: <Widget>[

               CircleAvatar(
                 radius: 26.0,
                 backgroundImage: (profile_img != null && profile_img != "") ? NetworkImage("$profile_img"):NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150',scale: 1.0),
                 backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
               ),
             ]
           ),

           Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
             child: new Column(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               children: <Widget>[
                 Container(
                   margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
                   child:  Text("$name",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff444444),fontSize: 16.0))
                 ),
                 screenName != 'edit' ?
                 GestureDetector(
                   child: Text("Edit Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, color: Colors.blue,decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Editprofile())
                     );
                   }
                 ):Container()

               ]
             )
           )


         ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        onPressed: () =>
        customFun.logout().then((_) =>
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Login(logout:true)))
        ),
        icon: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0,top: 4.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app,color: Color(0xff888888)),
            ),

          ]
        )
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

editprofile.dart

```
void _submitlogin() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    Map _data;

    if(form.validate()){
      if(_newpassword != _confirmpassword){
        setState(() {
          show_error = true;
          error_msg = "Confirm Password should match password";
        });
      }
      showProgressBar = true;
      customFun.readToken().then((val) {
        access_token = val;
        try{
          (() async {
            await restApis.postUpdateProfile(access_token,_name,_mobile,_oldpassword,_newpassword,_confirmpassword).then((val) => setState(() {
              // print("response");
               print(val);
              if(val["success"]){
                form.save();
                scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  content: Text(val["message"]),
                ));
                setState(() {
                  showProgressBar = false;
                  show_error = false;
                });
                _getProfleDetail();
              }else{
                showProgressBar = false;
                scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  content: Text(val["message"]),
                ));
              }
            }));
          })();
        }catch(e){
          setState(() {
            showProgressBar = false;
            //show_error = true;
            //error_msg = "The exception thrown is $e";
          });
          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            content: Text("The exception thrown is $e"),
          ));
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

THESE ARE THE MAIN FUNCTIONS AND WHEN I UPDATE MY PROFILE AND BACK FROM NAVIGATION BACK ICON ON EDIT PROFILE SCREEN ON MY HOME PAGE APP BAR PROFILE PHOTO AND THE NAME IS NOT UPDATING. NAME AND PROFILE PHOTO SHOULD BE UPDATED IN APP.

I need to call `getProfileData();` function when i am coming to home screen from edit profile screen.

UPDATED: My issue is when i update my image from updateprofile screen this result is not reflecting on the home screen.

Please let me know if any solution.

Comment: use futureBuilder method

Comment: `FutureBuilder` and package provider will solve nicely what you are trying to do. Post a full app example of what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated my question please check above.